# Differences in str representation of np.float64 vs native Python float

Tags: python, numpy

In the native Python `float` type, there appears to be no rounding when the `float` is cast to a `str`:

```
In [1]: foo = 0.24000000000000002

In [2]: print(str(foo))
0.24000000000000002

In [3]: print(repr(foo))
0.24000000000000002
```

However, when `np.float64` is cast to a `str`, rounding appears to take place.

```
In [4]: print(str(np.float64(foo)))
0.24

In [5]: print(repr(np.float64(foo)))
0.24000000000000002
```

What is the logic behind the rounding when `np.float64` is cast to a `str`?

Comment: I don't get that behavior, `numpy 1.15.3`, Python `3.6.7`

Comment: Both produce the same result for me. Which python version are you using?

Comment: I am using `numpy 1.13.3` and `Python 3.6.6`

Comment: What is the value of `sys.float_repr_style` on your machine?

Comment: `In [4]: sys.float_repr_style`:  `Out[4]: 'short'`

Comment: I'm guessing there was some change between the versions by which NumPy scalars stopped being affected by [`np.set_printoptions`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html), in order to make them behave more like Python primitive values.

Comment: browse the changelog https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/release.html

Comment: Yes, I think it must be [Many changes to array printing, disableable with the new “legacy” printing mode](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/release.html#many-changes-to-array-printing-disableable-with-the-new-legacy-printing-mode) from 1.14.0.